# Validation function not working in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, authentication

I have a Plugin named User Registration Plugin, and the process works fine, but it's causing an issue when fields are being validated.

After logging in with an incorrect email I receive an error message, but in the case of an incorrect password I receive none.

I checked the code in my plugin and it turns out that the function below isn't working, but I don't know why.

Any help is appreciated.

```
    // Modify error message on invalid username or password.
    function ur_login_error_message( $error ) {
        // Don't change login error messages on admin site .
        if ( isset( $_POST['redirect_to'] ) && false !== strpos( $_POST['redirect_to'], network_admin_url() ) ) {
            return $error;
        }

        $pos  = strpos( $error, 'incorrect' );     // Check if the error contains incorrect string.
        $pos2 = strpos( $error, 'Invalid' );       // Check if the error contains Invalid string.

        // Its the correct username with incorrect password.
        if ( is_int( $pos ) && isset( $_POST['username'] ) ) {

            $error = sprintf( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR:', 'user-registration' ) . '</strong>' . __( 'The password you entered for username %1$1s is incorrect. %2$2s', 'user-registration' ), $_POST['username'], "<a href='" . esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ) . "'>" . __( 'Lost Your Password?', 'user-registration' ) . '</a>' );
        } // It's invalid username.
        elseif ( is_int( $pos2 ) && isset( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
            $error = sprintf( '<strong>' . __( 'ERROR:', 'user-registration' ) . '</strong>' . __( 'Invalid username. %1s', 'user-registration' ), "<a href='" . esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ) . "'>" . __( 'Lost Your Password?', 'user-registration' ) . '</a>' );
        }

        return $error;
    }
```

Comment: As an aside, you don't want to tell someone that a password or user name are not correct. Use a more general message that simply says that the credentials are not valid. What you're trying to do there is a hackers delight. They just have to stumble across a user name then beat on it trying different passwords.

Comment: Hey thanks dave, thanks for the advice. Will do that but if any users enters a wrong password, No validation message is being shown to user, even if I provide a general message, it'll only show up when an username/email is invalid. The Password validation field is somehow not showing up for incorrect password (f.y.i it only works when a user doesn't enters a password and tries to proceed.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a [filter for Wordpress login_errors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_errors).

In the above link's example "*incorrect*" refers to password, and "*Invalid*" to username - they **($pos and £pos2) are used the other (wrong?) way round in your function**.

Also try replacing `strpos` (case sensitive) in your code by `stripos` (case insensitive).

As Dave says in comments, it is best not to indicate whether it is the username or whether it is password that is in error.  So you could also replace your 2 if - print blocks by a single one

```
if (  (is_int( $pos ) || is_int( $pos2 ) ) && isset( $_POST['username'] ) ) {
    $error =  # printf some "either username or password is invalid" message here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @scytale for your concern, But the problem is that even after following your instructions, the function itself is being unable to get executed so that the code compiles ... i meant that the plugin is not able to run the function code available in the page and thus simply its ignoring the messages also ... both of em...

Comment: Sorry Joy, with info provided no idea as to cause. If you provide details about the calling page someone may be able to help,

Comment: Hey @scytale thanks for your concern, actually since its a theme so i'm unable to trace that page/parts of page which after entering incorrect login details leading me to. I'm only aware of the custom page for login that i've created using the "User Registration" plugin, for the development. Its basically a Thimpress Theme, named "Eduma" and I asked for their support but getting no feedback from them either.